# How i can convert a decimal variable to hex in c?

Tags: c, hex, decimal

Hello I'm trying to convert a decimal value to a hex using C in order to store it on my variable `char data[]` and use the data later for something else. Does any one know how I can do it? I'm new to C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a number stored in a "char" variable, it is stored in the machine in binary. When you print the variable, you can chose how to display the variable. For example, to display it in decimal, you may do:

```
printf("The value in decimal is %d\n", x);
```

To display it in hex, you may do:

```
printf("The value in hex is %x\n", x);
```

You probably want to look at a book on C and check the printf formatting options, as you can do lots of things with how the value is displayed (as a character, octal, padding, etc.). Just keep in mind that the computer stores it in only one way. There is no conversion from one representation to another.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `%x` format specifier and a `sprintf`. Pass `data` as the first parameter, and the value to be printed as the last parameter:

```
int value = 12345;
char data[16];
sprintf(data, "%x", value); // This produces 3039
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/rc4YsU)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char       UCHAR;

typedef char                CHAR;  

typedef unsigned short int  UINT16;

typedef unsigned int        UINT32;

typedef float               FLOAT32;

typedef int                 INT32;

typedef short int           INT16;

void DecimalToHex(UCHAR *ucHexStringStored, UINT32 nDecimalValue){
    INT16 anHexValueStored[8];
    INT16 nPartialRemainder,ncnt1;
    UINT16 unLengthOfHexString = 0;

    while(nDecimalValue) {
        nPartialRemainder = nDecimalValue % 16;

        if(nPartialRemainder>9){
            nPartialRemainder = nPartialRemainder-10 + 17;
        }
        anHexValueStored[unLengthOfHexString++] = nPartialRemainder + '0';
        nDecimalValue /= 16;`enter code here`
    }

    CHAR ucHexStringConverted[unLengthOfHexString];
    for(ncnt1 = unLengthOfHexString-1 ; ncnt1>=0 ; ncnt1--){
        ucHexStringConverted[unLengthOfHexString-ncnt1-1]=anHexValueStored[ncnt1];
    };

    ucHexStringConverted[unLengthOfHexString]='\0';
    for(ncnt1=0 ; ncnt1 <= unLengthOfHexString ; ncnt1++)
    ucHexStringStored[ncnt1]=ucHexStringConverted[ncnt1];
}
int main() {
    UCHAR c[8];
    DecimalToHex(c,-6243);//Decimal value and it will be converted to Hex
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
    en
```

ter code here